# How to enable Secure Web Sockets on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Documentation exists for enabling insecure web sockets on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with an ALB, however, nothing appears to exist that shows how to enable *secure* websockets (wss://) on Elastic Beanstalk.

Looking for the .ebextensions configuration for enabling secure websockets on Elastic Beanstalk for a node app using the ws library.

Comment: create a HTTPS listener on ALB and this should provide wss between client and ALB.

Comment: ngnix still needs to be configured properly via ebextensions. I need that config